# Blender : Some objects disappear when I turn to camera mode (it's not the snapping I think)

Tags: object, blender, invisible

OK... here is the thing...

I am modeling a Star Wars Cruiser.. I'm doing pretty fine, but.. whenever I look through the camera, half of my ship disappears ?!  Now you might think it's the clipping, but that doesn't make sense, since the clipping is set to 0,1 mtr - 10.000 mtr, which should be more than enough. Besides that, the clipping is the same for both the visible and now disappeared objects...

Does anyone have any clue ? 
I also tried to change the Local view to Global view.. but no dice...

Here is a screenshot in not-camera view : [image: i.imgur.com/S3zIwml.png]

And here is one in camera view : i.imgur.com/XaxAHIN.png

[image]

I'm using **Blender 2.82**

Please let me know if you need more info or even a link to the model...

Comment: Here is a screenshot in not-camera view :  https://i.imgur.com/S3zIwml.png

And here is one in camera view : https://i.imgur.com/XaxAHIN.png

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got some help from a friend... Joshua Rooijakkers from the Netherlands...
He fixed the problem in seconds...

[image]

So ... it WAS the clipping.. the setting was just buried somewhere I didn't look...

Thanks Josh ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Objects disappear in camera view mode](https://youtu.be/Wk706Oj4Co8)While setting up my camera with the camera lock to view option selected, I noticed that on switching on to the camera view, the object had disappeared.

I tried zooming in and out, but that did not work. I exited the camera view and then selected the object in the outliner and then tried zooming in and out and then panning down and adjusting the view in the view port.  I could see that the object was now visible and that the camera was positioned below the object. That was because the camera was added wrt to the position of the cursor which was snapped to the world origin. I a sure many would have encountered such issues.

I then selected the camera to ascertain its position. Then by using the grab tool, I moved the camera along the Z axis just above the object and then switched to the camera view and selected the lock camera to
view option to adjust the camera view to the desired position.

This helped me locate my object in the camera view. Do let me know in the comments if there are other ways of dealing with this.